# Wordpress pretty permalinks "No Input File Specified" error

Tags: wordpress

I'm getting the dreaded "No Input File Specified" error when using pretty permalinks, but I think it's a WordPress problem, not a rewrite module problem.  I'm on IIS7 and WP 3.4.2. The pretty permalink is:

```
http://www.mydomain.com/blog/2012/09/20/post-name/
```

and *this is correctly rewriting* to:

```
http://www.mydomain.com/blog/index.php/2012/09/20/post-name/
```

I think the rewrite is correct because when I go to this latter url manually, I still get the error.  So I think the problem lies in WordPress.  For completeness, though, here's the rewrite rule:

> ```
>    <rule name="Main Rule" stopProcessing="true">
>       <match url="^blog/(.+)" />
>       <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
>         <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
>         <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
>       </conditions>
>       <action type="Rewrite" url="/blog/index.php/{R:1}" />
>     </rule>
> ```

There are a lot of posts on this issue on SO, but they all seem to be rewrite issues, so I don't *think* this is a duplicate of any question where the problem is the one I'm having.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it was a rewrite problem, sort of.  In the pattern above, I didn't take into account that the site is on a shared host, and `/blog` is actually pointing to `\subfolder\blog`.  Changing it as follows fixed it:

```
   <rule name="Main Rule" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^blog/(.+)" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="/subfolder/blog/index.php/{R:1}" />
    </rule>
```

This isn't ideal, because I had to hardcode the name of the subfolder, but for now, I'll take it.